# Assistance needed configuring two routers

Tags: router, internet, lan, connection

I need help **configuring 2 routers** for my home internet please.
My principal router is also a modem ( Vodafone.de - Kabeldeutschland modem/router )and my second router is from Linksys. Both have wireless capabilities.

I have actually managed to connect them and I have cable/wireless internet on both routers but i'm asking for your help because I know I have configured something wrong because internet disconnects frequently on every device connected to both routers.

I don't know if I should do a **LAN- LAN** or **LAN- WAN** connection but from what I see, I have done a LAN- WAN. Currently my first router has a Lease time of 1hour. One more thing :D my laptop is always connected to the second router and when I connect it to the first one, it doesn't have internet.

Sorry for the long post. Just trying to give you as much details as possible.
Thank you in advance

The **first router/modem** gets internet from a coaxial cable. Local ip address is `192.168.0.1` and subnet mask `255.255.255.0`. The first router/modem gives ip from `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.254` An ethernet cable connects an ethernet port of the first modem with the internet port of the second modem ( so I guess its a LAN-WAN connection ).

The **second router** local ip is `192.168.1.1` and subnet mask `255.255.255.0` . The second router has DHCP enabled and gives ip from `192.168.1.100` Now, if someone cares enough to help, I am grateful, if not, please refrain yourself from giving useless comments please

Comment: Down vote... You have given us no information on how these are connected or technical information on the network(s) that would be needed to troubleshoot this. Plus this topic, or a variant of it, is asked and answered every few days.

Comment: How they connected, wired Ethernet? If so,  this is simple, set the IP address of router 2 to 192.168.0.2 (or other IP address outside R1's DHCP range) and disable DHCP in R2, connect Lan to Lan.

Comment: The first router/modem gets internet from a coaxial cable. Local ip address is 192.168.0.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0.
The first router/modem gives ip from 192.168.0.2  to  192.168.0.254

An ethernet cable connects an ethernet port of the first modem with the internet port of the second modem ( so i guess its a LAN-WAN connection ). the second router local ip is 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0 . The second router has DHCP enabled and gives ip from 192.168.1.100
Now, if someone cares enough to help, i am grateful, if not, please refrain yourself from giving useless comments please

Comment: The setup you describe is exactly the same way as mine, also Germany, also cable internet provider (though not vodafone/kabel deutschland). Do the connection problems occur also to wired devices or only if connected wirelessly to the cable-modem/router?

Comment: it occurs to wired devices too

Comment: Do you have the wireless running on both routers? and are you running this setup as sort of a repeater or are the routers right next to each other?

Comment: both routers have wireless on. one is on the first floor and the second one is on the second floor. they're connected by a 50m ethernet cable. i changed the configuration to a LAN-LAN connection and the problem seems to be less frequent now but still happens

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide on setting up 2 routers. This will assist you, shows pictures of how and what ports you should be setup, and how to configure each router...  http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Routers

Comment: i did, the problem still persists. my ISP says its not their fault. don't know what to do

Comment: always getting these two errors on google chrome. don't know why skype works fine while chrome doesnt
DNS probe started
DNS probe finished no internet

Comment: Could you please edit in the relevant parts of your answer. That way it will keep working if (or rather *when*) the link dies.